# React native bluetooth escpos printer Failed to generate APK

Tags: reactjs, react-native, printing, bluetooth

Trying to implement react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer
i can build the application successfully but cannt generate apk

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1" 
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you linked it properly?

Comment: Yes I did, and the app can build successfully in emulator

Answer (score 0):

I just change buildToolVesion and compileSdkVersion

and my react-native version is

```
"react": "17.0.2", "react-native": "0.68.2",
```

**Go to the dependency build.gradle folder YOUR_PROJECT/node_modules/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
        jcenter { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        maven {url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"}
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
        dependencies {
            // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
            classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        }
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
         buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion = 21
            targetSdkVersion = 31
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            }
        }
    }
    
    repositories {
        jcenter { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        maven {url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"}
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'  // From node_modules
        implementation group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-v4', version: '27.0.0'
        implementation "com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0"
    }
```